# Position of a point in a circle

Tags: math, geometry

Hello again first part is working like a charm, thank you everyone.

But I've another question...

## As I've no interface, is there a way to do the same thing with out not knowing the radius of the circle?

Should have refresh the page CodeMonkey solution is exactly what I was looking for...

Thank you again.

============================

First I'm not a developer, I'm a simple woodworker that left school far too early...

I'm trying to make one of my tool to work with an autonomous robot.
I made them communicate by reading a lot of tutorials.

But I have one problem I cant figure out.

Robot expect position of the tool as (X,Y) but tool's output is (A,B,C)
A is the distance from tool to north 
B distance to east
C distance at 120 degree clockwise from east axe

the border is a circle, radius may change, and may or may not be something I know.

I've been on that for 1 month, and I can't find a way to transform those value into the position.

I made a test with 3 nails on a circle I draw on wood, and if I have the distance there is only one position possible, so I guess its possible.
But how?

Also, if someone as an answer I'd love pseudo code not code so I can practice.

If there is a tool to make a drawing I can use to make it clearer can you point it out to me?

Thank you.

hope it helps :

[image: http://imgur.com/a/CvoNB]

X, Y are coordinate from center, Da,Db, Dc are known.

Trying to make it more clear (sorry its so clear in my head).

X,Y are the coordinate of the point where is the tool (P).
Center is at 0,0

A is the point where vertical line cut the circle from P, with Da distance P to A;

B is the point where horizontal line cuts the circle fom P, with Db distance P to B.

C is the point where the line at 120 clockwise from horizontal cuts the circle from P, with Dc distance P to C.

Output from tool is an array of int (unit mm): A=123, B=114, C=89
Those are the only informations I have

thanks for all the ideas I'll try them at home later,
Hope it works :)

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by X and Y here. If you can make a diagram it will be helpful.

Comment: Are A,B, and C angles from the origin, or points with XY coordinates?

Comment: There are 2 points in the figure, A and B. Which point do you want the X and Y coordinates of exactly.

Comment: I need the position of P,
P is my drill head and A,B,C are the point where my range sensor hit the circle of protection.

Comment: Do you know the XY coordinates of A, B and C?

Comment: No, I only know distance from P to A,B,C and the diameter of the circle.

Comment: What this has to do with c/c++ tags?

Comment: @A.albin: OK, give me a sec.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès the fact that I try to put it in a c code and ask for way to do it and make it into code maybe?

Comment: At least choose c or c++, not both.

Comment: Can you give us some examples from your nail board, your output from your tool (A,B,C) etc.? I think it would help clarify the question and help us give you a better answer

Comment: @A.albin thanks for adding an example of A, B, C. As I see it now this A, B, C is actually what you call Da, Db, Dc in your drawing. You said you also know the diameter of the circle and that the center of the circle is at (0,0), correct?

Comment: @CodeMonkey thats correct, but Im using various protection circle so it might change. So if I can find the position withou having the Diameter as a parameter it will be "better" as the robot doest have an interface I can't put data into without sending a new hex file

Comment: Something is still unclear to me. Are Da, Db, Dc straight-line distances from P to the points A, B, C, or are they vertical, horizontal or oblique distances as your fourth paragraph seems to mean ? This makes a big difference. How are they actually measured ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Seems to me (and this is the interpretation used by the answers as well) that A is the vertical distance to the circle, B is the horizontal distance to the circle, and C is the oblique distance, as you say.

Comment: @Linuxios: thanks, but I am asking the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you know X and Y. R is the radius of the circle.

```
|(X, Y + Da)| = R
|(X + Db, Y)| = R
|(X - cos(pi/3) * Dc, Y - cos(pi/6) * Dc)| = R
```

Assuming we don't know the radius R. We can still say

```
|(X, Y + Da)|^2 = |(X + Db, Y)|^2
=> X^2 + (Y+Da)^2 = (X+Db)^2 + Y^2
=> 2YDa + Da^2 = 2XDb + Db^2 (I)
```

and denoting cos(pi/3)*Dc as c1 and cos(pi/6)*Dc as c2:

```
|(X, Y + Da)|^2 = |(X - c1, Y - c2)|^2
=> X^2 + Y^2 + 2YDa + Da^2 = X^2 - 2Xc1 + c1^2 + Y^2 - 2Yc2 + c2^2
=> 2YDa + Da^2 = - 2Xc1 + c1^2 - 2Yc2 + c2^2
=> Y = (-2Xc1 + c1^2 + c2^2 - Da^2) / 2(c2+Da) (II)
```

Putting (II) back in the equation (I) we get:

```
=> (-2Xc1 + c1^2 + c2^2 - Da^2) Da / (c2+Da) + Da^2 = 2XDb + Db^2
=> (-2Xc1 + c1^2 + c2^2 - Da^2) Da + Da^2 * (c2+Da) = 2XDb(c2+Da) + Db^2 * (c2+Da)
=> (-2Xc1 + c1^2 + c2^2) Da + Da^2 * c2 = 2XDb(c2+Da) + Db^2 * (c2+Da)

=> X = ((c1^2 + c2^2) Da + Da^2 * c2 - Db^2 * (c2+Da)) / (2Dbc2 + 2Db*Da + 2Dac1) (III)
```

Knowing X you can get Y by calculating (II).

You can also make some simplifications, e.g. c1^2 + c2^2 = Dc^2

Putting this into Python (almost Pseudocode):

```
import math


def GetXYR(Da, Db, Dc):
    c1 = math.cos(math.pi/3) * Dc
    c2 = math.cos(math.pi/6) * Dc

    X = ((c1**2 + c2**2) * Da + Da**2 * c2 - Db * Db * (c2 + Da)) / (2 * Db * c2 + 2 * Db * Da + 2 * Da * c1)
    Y = (-2*X*c1 + c1**2 + c2**2 - Da**2) / (2*(c2+Da))
    R = math.sqrt(X**2 + (Y+Da)**2)
    R2 = math.sqrt(Y**2 + (X+Db)**2)
    R3 = math.sqrt((X - math.cos(math.pi/3) * Dc)**2 + (Y - math.cos(math.pi/6) * Dc)**2)
    return (X, Y, R, R2, R3)

(X, Y, R, R2, R3) = GetXYR(123.0, 114.0, 89.0)

print((X, Y, R, R2, R3))
```

I get the result (X, Y, R, R2, R3) = (-8.129166703588021, -16.205081335032794, 107.1038654949096, 107.10386549490958, 107.1038654949096)

Which seems reasonable if both Da and Db are longer than Dc, then both coordinates are probably negative.

I calculated the Radius from three equations to cross check whether my calculation makes sense. It seems to fulfill all three equations we set up in the beginning.

Comment: I used a not refreshed page, and didn't see your answer until now, will try soon as it seems to e exactly what I need :O, well it works perfectly

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I hope you succeed in your project :-).

Answer (score 2):

Basic geometry.  I decided to give up having the circle at the origin.  We don't know the center of the circle yet.  What you do have, is three points on that circle.  Let's try having the tool's position, given as P, as the new (0,0).  This thus resolves to finding a circle given three points: (0, Da); (Db,0), and back off at 120° at Dc distance.

Pseudocode:

- Calculate a line from A to B: we'll call it AB.  Find AB's halfway point.  Calculate a line perpendicular to AB, through that midpoint (e.g. the cross product of AB and a unit Z axis finds the perpendicular vector).
- Calculate a line from B to C (or C to A works just as well): we'll call it BC.  Find BC's halfway point.  Calculate a line perpendicular to BC, through that midpoint.
- Calculate where these two lines cross.  This will be the origin of your circle.

Since P is at (0,0), the negative of your circle's origin will be your tool's coordinates relative to the circle's origin.  You should be able to calculate anything you need relative to that, now.

Midpoint between two points: X=(X1+X2)/2.  Y=(Y1+Y2)/2.

The circle's radius can be calculated using, e.g. point A and the circle's origin: R=sqrt(sqr((Ax-CirX)+sqr(Ay-CirY))

Distance from the edge: circle's radius - tool's distance from the circle's center via Pythagorean Theorem again.

Comment: P; which is to say, the position of the tool, reckoned as (0,0)

Comment: OK. This is very clever, nice solution! I went at it with the brute force algebra, and the equations certainly don't work out too pretty :)

Comment: Ok, I will try that. but Im not sure I can...I dont have ABC coordinates, so how do I get the line between them? As far as I know I need coordinates of two points to get a line, no?

Comment: @A.albin that's why I think actual output would help in finding an answer.

Comment: @A.albin: The premise of this answer is to reformulate the question, assuming that P lies at (0,0). If P lies at (0, 0), A lies at (0, D_A), and B lies at (D_B, 0). The geometry for C is a little more involved, I believe C is given by (D_C * cos(4/3 * Pi), D_C * sin(4/3 * Pi)).

Comment: @A.albin: The method outlined by CodeLurker then allows you to find the center of the circle in this new coordinate system, which can then be used to find the offset between that point and P (which here, again, is (0,0)) to find the position of P in the original coordinate system where the center of the circle is at the origin.

Comment: Thank you for making it clearer, will try after work, sorry Im a slow learner

Comment: @A.albin: Sure! Best of luck with your project, and let us know if you need more clarification.

Comment: I made some changes, to help make it be more understandable.  I changed over to using the original variable P, for what I called T, for Tool.  I've also better specified the three points I had in mind, and said in as many words, that P (what I called T) was now (0,0).  I also introduced line AB and BC terminology.

Comment: @CodeLurker thank you its far easier for me to understand it, to get C(Xc,Yc) I need to use trigonometrie right?

Comment: Sorta.  You could just hardcode the result of the trig functions to get the slopes, and then multiply by length to get (Xc, Yc).  It is 120°, and not a more convenient 135°, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is know a "circumscribed circle". You have a triangle define by 3 distances at given angles from your robot position, then you can construct the circumscribed circle from these three points (see [Circumscribed circle from Wikipedia - section "Other properties"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle)). So you know the diameter (if needed).

It is also known that the meeting point of perpendicular bisector of triangle sides is the center of the circumscribed circle.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer, but it's my impression that the OP wants the coordinates of the point P in the circle, not the circle itself.

Comment: I will need a simplier answer or more details, I can't understand those math.
Also doesn't that need me to know the angles of the triangle abc? I dont have them.

Answer (score 1):

Let's `a=Da, b=Db`. The we can write a system for points A and B at the circumference:

```
(x+b)^2 + y^2 = r^2
(y+a)^2 + x^2 = r^2
```

After transformations we have quadratic equation

```
y^2 * (4*b^2+4*a^2) + y * (4*a^3+4*a*b^2) + b^4-4*b^2*r^2+a^4+2*a^2*b^2 = 0
or 
AA * y^2  + BB * y + CC = 0
where coefficients are
AA = (4*b^2+4*a^2)
BB = (4*a^3+4*a*b^2)
CC = b^4-4*b^2*r^2+a^4+2*a^2*b^2
```

So calculate AA, BB, CC coefficients, find solutions y1,y2 of quadratic eqiation, then get corresponding x1, x2 values using

```
 x = (a^2 - b^2 + 2 * a * y) / (2 * b)
```

and choose real solution pair (where coordinate is inside the circle)

Quick checking:
`a=1,b=1,r=1` gives coordinates `0,0`, as expected (and false `1,-1` outside the circle)
`a=3,b=4,r=5` gives coordinates (rough) `0.65, 1.96` at the picture, distances are about 3 and 4.

[image]

Delphi code (does not check all possible errors) outputs `x: 0.5981  y: 1.9641`

```
var
  a, b, r, a2, b2: Double;
  aa, bb, cc, dis, y1, y2, x1, x2: Double;
begin
  a := 3;
  b := 4;
  r := 5;
  a2 := a * a;
  b2:= b * b;
  aa := 4 * (b2 + a2);
  bb := 4 * a * (a2 + b2);
  cc := b2 * b2 - 4 * b2 * r * r + a2 * a2 + 2 * a2 * b2;
  dis := bb * bb - 4 * aa * cc;
  if Dis < 0 then begin
    ShowMessage('no solutions');
    Exit;
  end;

  y1 := (- bb - Sqrt(Dis)) / (2 * aa);
  y2 := (- bb + Sqrt(Dis)) / (2 * aa);
  x1 := (a2 - b2 + 2 * a * y1) / (2 * b);
  x2 := (a2 - b2 + 2 * a * y2) / (2 * b);

  if x1 * x1 + y1 * y1 <= r * r then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('x: %6.4f  y: %6.4f', [x1, y1]))
  else
  if x2 * x2 + y2 * y2 <= r * r then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('x: %6.4f  y: %6.4f', [x2, y2]));
```

Comment: is there a way to do the same thing with radius unknown on the first iteration ? also your code is in python right? (just curious)

Comment: No, this approach uses radius (but ignores the third distance). To avoid radius usage, you need circumscribed circle approach. Code is in Delphi (Pascal)

Answer (score 0):

From your diagram you have point `P` that you need it's `X` & `Y` coordinate. So we need to find `Px` and `Py` or `(Px,Py)`. We know that `Ax = Px` and `By = Py`. We can use these for substitution if needed. We know that `C` & `P` create a line and all lines have slope in the form of `y = mx + b`. Where the slope is `m` and the y intercept is `b`. We don't know `m` or `b` at this point but they can be found. We know that the angle of between two vectors where the vectors are `CP` and `PB` gives an angle of `120°`, but this does not put the angle in standard position since this is a `CW` rotation. When working with circles and trig functions along with linear equations of slope within them it is best to work in standard form. So if this line of `y = mx + b` where the points `C` & `P` belong to it the angle above the horizontal line that is parallel to the horizontal axis that is made by the points `P` & `B` will be `180° - 120° = 60°` We also know that the cos angle between two vectors is also equal to the dot product of those vectors divided by the product of their magnitudes.

We don't have exact numbers yet but we can construct a formula: Since theta = `60°` above the horizontal in the standard position we know that the slope `m` is also the tangent of that angle; so the slope of this line is tan(60°). So let's go back to our linear equation `y = tan(60°)x + b`. Since `b` is the `y` intercept we need to find what `x` is when `y` is equal to `0`. Since we still have three undefined variables `y`, `x`, and `b` we can use the points on this line to help us here. We know that the points `C` & `P` are on this line. So this vector of `y = tan(60°)x + b` is constructed from `(Px, Py) - (Cx, Cy)`. The vector is then `(Px-Cx, Py-Cy)` that has an angle of `60°` above the horizontal that is parallel to the horizontal axis. We need to use another form of the linear equation that involves the points and the slope this time which happens to be `y - y1 = m(x - x1)` so this then becomes `y - Py = tan(60°)(x - Px)` well I did say earlier that we could substitute so let's go ahead and do that: `y - By = tan(60°)(x - Ax)` then `y - By = tan(60°)x - tan(60°)Ax`. And this becomes known if you know the actual coordinate points of `A` & `B`. The only thing here is that you have to convert your angle of `120°` to standard form. It all depends on what your known and unknowns are. So if you need `P` and you have both `A` & `B` are known from your diagram the work is easy because the points you need for `P` will be `P(Ax,By)`. And since you already said that you know `Da`, `Db` & `Dc` with their lengths then its just a matter of apply the correct trig functions with the proper angle and or using the Pythagorean Theorem to find the length of another leg of the triangle. It shouldn't be all that hard to find what `P(x,y)` is from the other points. You can use the trig functions, linear equations, the Pythagorean theorem, vector calculations etc. If you can find the equation of the line that points `C` & `P` knowing that `P` has `A's` `x` value and has `B's` `y` value and having the slope of that line that is defined by the tangent above the horizontal which is `180° - phi` where `phi` is the angle you are giving that is `CW` rotation and `theta` would be the angle in standard position or above the horizontal you have a general form of `y - By = tan(180° - phi)(x - Ax)` and from this equation you can find any point on that line.

There are other methods such as using the existing points and the vectors that they create between each other and then generate an equilateral triangle using those points and then from that equilateral if you can generate one, you can use the perpendicular bisectors of that triangle to find the centroid of that triangle. That is another method that can be done. The only thing you may have to consider is the linear translation of the line from the origin. Thus you will have a shift in the line of (Ax - origin, By - origin) and to find one set the other to 0 and vise versa. There are many different methods to find it.

I just showed you several mathematical techniques that can help you to find a general equation based on your known(s) and unknown(s). It just a matter of recognizing which equations work in which scenario. Once you recognize the correct equations for the givens; the rest is fairly easy. I hope this helps you.

**EDIT**

I did forget to mention one thing; and that is the line of `CP` has a point on the edge of the circle defined by `(cos(60°), sin(60°))` in the 1st quadrant. In the third quadrant you will have a point on this line and the circle defined by `(-cos(60°), -sin(60°))` provided that this line goes through the origin `(0,0)` where there is no `y` nor `x` intercepts and if this is the case then the point on the circle at either end and the origin will be the radius of that circle.

Comment: A tip; you can treat any circle as a Unit Circle where it's radius is = 1 arbitrarily to make all of your trigonometric functions, conversions from degrees to radians, finding points and vectors, defining triangles within the circle etc., much easier. The reason for this is that the circumference of all circles when they are unit circles are `2PI` with a vector rotation of `360°` and the area of all unit circles is `PI units squared`. Another thing to help is to know that both the equation of the circle and the Pythagorean Theorem are the same.

Comment: This interest me a lot, it means that I could do the whole process without the struggle I know have (cf. updated post), right?

Comment: Well the thing is there are many approaches to solving your problem; you can do it linearly with 2 points on a line that has a specific slope provided you have all the information that would satisfy any of the equations of a line; you could do it trigonometrically, or even geometrically provided you have the information needed. Visually A triangle, rectangle (even square) and a circle don't appear to look a like but they are all related because of the properties of points on a line that make a line segment or vector and the properties of vectors and matrices and rotations between vectors.

Comment: For example given any two points on a line that make a line segment from them you can construct a triangle by any third arbitrary point not on that line, you can construct a square, or a circle that has either a radius or a diameter that those two points make. The same can be said for any other polygonal shape except more points would be needed for the necessary vectors to create the said shape. Remember that when a point is shared between two vectors as a point of intersection, rotation, reflection, symmetry it is then considered a vertex and a series or set of them are vertices.

Comment: You just have to find a general equation that will give you the desired results from the known and if you have more than one unknown then you may have to take steps to solve for that known first then substitute back into the original equation to give you the desired answer. Maybe grabbing a High School or early College Calculus based Physics book and doing the exercise for basic kinematic motion and forces might help you. Such as having a weight being pulled by a rope up an incline of a certain degree with a specific amount of tension and friction and then finding the force needed to move it..

Comment: ... a specified distance within a specified amount of time, or to find the force needed given a certain amount of acceleration or velocity or momentum. Or finding the amount of Work that is done. These types of problems helps in building your skills of finding and or constructing equations to find solutions with several unknown variables.

Comment: No problem; thought I would at least help with the mathematical part; once you have that then it should be easy to put that into any arbitrary programmable language even assembly.